# Deploying application via API with docker: docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by docker)

Tags: python, docker, api

I am creating docker containers to deploy my apps via API, so there is a docker for app_manager that exposes an API and a docker container for an application(s) itself. Both app_manager and deploying applications are written in Python. I am testing deployment locally prior to deploying on the server. After the successful installation of app_manager I sent a request to deploy a specific version of my application via app_manager API (that uses subprocess.run) in a web browser. However, the response is null and by checking the docker logs I found the following error:

```
docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by docker)
```

I do not use Jenkins and adding libc6 library to DockerFile does not change anything. I still can install my app in Docker container manually with a couple of bash commands. I can
even deploy my app in the VSCode editor via subprocess.run() directly. However, how can I fix it, so I can deploy via sending API request?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, Python 3.8, Docker version 20.10.12, build 20.10.12-0ubuntu4

Thank you

Comment: In general, this means you installed a package (in this case, Docker itself) that was compiled for a different Linux distro (or distro release) than the one you're actually running. Don't do that; make sure the software you install was compiled for the specific distro you're actually running. (You might also think about switching to a package manager like [Nix](https://nixos.org/), which doesn't let this rule be broken at all).

Comment: (If you installed a copy of Docker built for a different, non-LTS Ubuntu release -- or a prior LTS release that used a different libc -- f/e, that would be consistent with the issue described)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Charles Duffy, reinstalling Xubuntu 20.04 instead of Ubuntu 22.04 and installing the latest docker (which is docker 20.10.12, build 20.10.12-0ubuntu4) solved the issue